# Pyspark fails when reading all parquet files in directory but succeeds when files processed individually

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have run into an issue where my pyspark job fails intermittently.
When I read all the parquet files from a directory using code below, it throws an exception        ***File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 717, in read_int
raise EOFError
EOFError***

```
inputPathWithData = []
    if (path.exists(input)):
        inputPathWithData.append(input + "\\*.parquet")

    if (len(inputPathWithData) > 0):
        parquetFile = spark.read.parquet(*inputPathWithData)
        parquetFile.createOrReplaceTempView("imp_parquetFile")
        imp_df = spark.sql("SELECT  * FROM imp_parquetFile as imp")
        imp_df.write.json(output_path +"Single", compression="gzip")
```

However if I read the file individually it all works as expected

```
i = 0
for input_file in os.listdir(input) :
    i+=1
    parquetFile = spark.read.parquet(input + input_file)
    parquetFile.createOrReplaceTempView("imp_parquetFile")
    try:
        imp_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM imp_parquetFile")
        imp_df.write.json(output_path + '_ '+ str(i), compression="gzip")
    except:
        print("Issue with Filename: {0}".format(input_file))
```

The code to initialize spark is

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("scratch_test") \
    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "100") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "10G") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify each and every parquet file. Just read the whole folder.

```
df=spark.read.parquet("/folder/")
```

Comment: Thanks! .in my real use case I read files from multiple folders. is there a way to read parquet files from multiple folders like I am currently doing for multiple files?

Comment: You can put directories in a list and read it just like you are doing now. No need put *.parquet `dir_list = ['/dir1/','/dir2/']  df=spark.read.parquet(*dir_list)`